Warum hier Akkusativ?

Therapeuten sind Personen, die anderen Menschen helfen.

Ich habe immer gedacht, dass ich mit "Helfen" immer Dativ benutzen sollte.
Wenn ich schon das Bezugswort kenne, bzw. Personen, dann wird der Satz:

Therapeuten sind Personen, denen anderen Menschen helfen.

Aber es ist nicht richtig, könnte mir bitte jmd. helfen?

Der zweite Satz ist grammatikalisch in Ordnung, aber von der Logik her falsch. Er drückt aus, dass ein Therapeut eine Person ist, der geholfen wird, d.h. ander Menschen leisten Hilfe, und der Therapeut erhält die Hilfe. Im ersten Satz ist ein Therapeut derjenige, der Hilfe leistet, und die anderen Menschen sind die, welche Hilfe bekommen.

Du denkst auch richtig, nur die grammatikalische Analyse ist nicht ganz richtig: "anderen Menschen" steht im Dativ und das "die" ist kein Artikel sondern ein Relativpronomen und gleichzeitig Subjekt, welches diesen Nebensatz einleitet.
Hauptsatz:

Therapeuten sind Personen

Nebensatz, welcher 'Personen' näher beschreibt:

(die) (anderen Menschen) (helfen)
(Subjekt) (Dativ-Objekt) (Verb)

Deine Umformulierung des Satzes

Therapeuten sind Personen, denen anderen Menschen helfen

hingegen ist so nicht korrekt, weil dem Nebensatz ein Subjekt fehlt ("denen" steht im Dativ und kann damit nicht das Subjekt des Nebensatzes sein, "anderen Menschen" steht auch im Dativ, aber "helfen" kann keine zwei Dativ-Objekte haben). Man könnte hingegen den Satz bilden

Patienten sind Personen, denen andere Menschen helfen

Dieser Satz hat aber eine andere Bedeutung (darum habe ich auch das Subjekt des Hauptsatzes ausgetauscht): "Denen" ist dann das Dativ-Objekt zum Verb "helfen" und "andere Menschen" das Subjekt des Nebensatzes.

Was genau ist der - grammatikalische - Unterschied zwischen "Patienten" und "Therapeuten"? Tatsächlich sind Therapeuten durchaus Personen, denen andere Menschen (nämlich ihre Patienten) helfen: indem sie ihnen Geld zukommen lassen, das sie für andere, vernünftigere Dinge ausgeben könnten.

Der grammatikalische Unterschied ist natürlich keiner. Mit Deiner Begründung müsste man auch nicht das Subjekt des Hauptsatzes ändern; ich finde es in meiner Version den Unterschied in der Bedeutung und darauf basierenden Grammatik (des Nebensatzes) aber leichter verständlich.

@bakunin : Der Patient ist der Kranke. Er braucht Hilfe. Der Therapeut ist (z.B.) der Arzt. Er hilft dem Patienten. Der Patient bezahlt den Therapeuten. Das ist schon ein Unterschied - ähnlich wie der Unterschied zwischen dem Gast und dem Koch in einem Restaurant.

@user1934428: und in welcher Beziehung ist dieser Unterschied grammatikalisch relevant? Siehe planetmakers Begründung oben, die zwar nachvollziehbar, aber eben nicht grammatikalischer Natur ist.

Das sind beides grammatikalisch korrekte Sätze.

"…, die anderen Menschen helfen" - "andere Menschen" (im Dativ) sind die, die die Hilfe empfangen; das Subjekt des Satzes (die, die die Hilfe leisten) ist das, was im Hauptsatz erwähnt wurde
"…, denen andere Menschen helfen" – "andere Menschen" (im Nominativ) sind die, die die Hilfe leisten; das Dativobjekt des Satzes (die, die die Hilfe empfangen) ist das, was im Hauptsatz erwähnt wurde

Sinngemäß ist natürlich das erste gemeint: Therapeuten (Subjekt) helfen anderen Menschen (Dativobjekt). Therapeuten sind die, die die Hilfe leisten. Andere Menschen sind die, die die Hilfe empfangen.
Das funktioniert bei einem Akkusativobjekt übrigens genau so: der Mann, den der Hund gebissen hat (d.h. der Hund hat den Mann gebissen) vs. der Mann, der den Hund gebissen hat (d.h. der Mann hat den Hund gebissen).
